# How to stick a footer to the bottom of the window ONLY when scrolling up would cause the footer to not be displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have a jQuery plugin that makes pages dynamic (found here: http://css-tricks.com/dynamic-page-replacing-content/ - Demo here: http://css-tricks.com/examples/DynamicPage)

My nav bar is in the footer (I know this is not generally a good idea but it suits the layout and objective of my website).

When there is not much content on the page, obviously the footer is in view on the window so no action needs to be taken. However, when a longer dynamic page is loaded which requires a scroll bar, the footer is pushed out of the window to make space for the content.
I want the footer to STOP and fix itself to the bottom of the window if the dynamic page creates a scrollbar, essentially so the navigation is *always* in view.

I've looked at other solutions on this site, but it's all either to permanently stick the footer to the bottom of the window, or only fix to the top when scrolling. I've tried inverting those solution values (i.e. changing top to bottom) but to no avail.

Could anyone help?

Comment: From your description I would think that you do want to "permanently stick the footer to the bottom of the window", no?

Comment: No - when There is not much content on the page, the footer will 'cling' to the content and move up so that it's essentially in the middle of the page.
At that point I don't want it clinging to the bottom of the screen, only when scrolling up would cause it to disappear from view.

Answer (score 0):

wrap in a DIV with overflow auto or scroll

Comment: you could put your footer content after the wrapped div and set the height of the wrapped div to the height of the window minus height of the footer. You could check the height of the content first to see if it exceeds this height.